# How to remove "octocat/Spoon-Knife" from my feed in Git?

Tags: github

After signing up for Git and going through the tutorial, I ended up Forking the Spoon-Knife repository and all subsequent actions performed on the repository are showing up in my feed.

I have un-watched the repository:
[image: Unwatched Repo]

Yet still the actions are displaying in my feed:
[image: Current Git Feed]

How can I remove these items from my feed?  I notice these are from over 12 days ago, so I'm not sure if my un-watching has had any effect or if there hasn't been any activity on the repository.  Has anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unwatching** prevents new activity from being added to your feed. However, old activities still remain.

As you can see by peeking at the **[events](https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Spoon-Knife/events)** of the repository, some activity occurred since you unwatched Octocat.

Comment: So, no way to clear those items.  They will eventually be pushed down by other activity, but they will still remain.  Correct?